# Downgrade Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3 to beta

Tags: ionic2

I am using `Ionic 2`, and would like to downgrade the `Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3` to the `beta` version.

```
ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.31
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.17
OS:
Node Version: v6.2.2
```

I have tried the following:

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
npm install -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.31
```

But as you can see, all this did was downgrade the `Ionic CLI Version`.

**Question**

How do I downgrade the `Ionic Framework Version`?

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

My `package.json` has the folliwng:

`"ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-rc.3",`

Do I need to change this to:

`"ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-beta.31",`

Then do I run something to make the change take affect?

**UPDATE**

I tried deleting `node_modules` (from `...\AppData\Roaming\npm`), but now I get:

```
npm install
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.15
npm WARN @angular/core@2.2.4 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/core@2.2.4 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.6.21 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/http@2.2.4 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser@2.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.2.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.2.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ionic/cloud-angular@0.4.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=2.0.0-rc.0 <2.0.0-rc.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN accounts-phone@0.0.1 requires a peer of meteor-client-side@~0.2.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@2.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3 requires a peer of @angular/forms@2.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3 requires a peer of @angular/http@2.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3 requires a peer of @angular/platform-server@2.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.3 requires a peer of zone.js@~0.6.26 but none was installed.
npm WARN theWhoZoo@ No repository field.
npm WARN theWhoZoo@ No license field.
```

There is no `node_modules` folder now.

Comment: tried `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`?

Comment: Thanks Ivaro, I tried but now I can't install npm (see above for details). Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like your project's `node_modules` are still present. (since it's still talking about `2.0.0-rc.3`. Yes, update your `package.json`, remove project's `node_modules` and reinstall.

Comment: If it then complains about `2.0.0-beta.31 requires a peer of ...` change the version number to the one suggested of the corresponding package in your `package.json`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this package.json for beta11 , i used this one to downgrade

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.11",
    "ionic-native": "1.3.17",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "2.2.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.5",
    "ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-fonts-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-html-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-sass-build": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-scripts-copy": "^2.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-tslint": "^1.0.0",
    "tslint-ionic-rules": "0.0.4",
    "run-sequence": "1.1.5"
  },
  "name": "hhbuyer",
  "description": "hhbuyer: An Ionic project",
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```